# Is it okay to return facade after creating an object from factory?

Tags: design-patterns, factory, facade

I guess doing this functionally would not harm, but I wanted to understand if it causes ambiguity in understanding the code.

I would like to explain using a simple example where I have a **`ProcessFactory`** which creates **`Process`** instances internally but returns a **`ProcessManager`** instead of **`Process`** instance.

And, **`ProcessManager`** is a class which adapts some of the **`Process`** functionality and adds more functions related to management of process.

The reason for doing this is that the client is not required to deal with the complex functionality which a `Process` provides but only needs to manage some aspects of it thru `ProcessManager`, while manager also adds some extra functionality on its own.

Comment: I don't see how returning a ProcessManager rather than a Process would be any harder to understand. As a user of your API, I'll read the javadoc of your factory, see that it returns a ProcessManager, look at its javadoc, and use it. I would do the exact same thing if it returned a Process. That said, if your ProcessFactory returns ProcessManager instances, I would name it ProcessManagerFactory.

Comment: So It should be okay to do so. About calling the factory class as ProcessManagerFactory, I want to mention that we want the API user to understand that a `Process` is being created by using the Factory method, which has a associated manager which will be returned to API user. So now I can explain in api doc that ProcessFactory will create Processes which you can manage by ProcessManager.